# Why NSObject's instance method could be called as a class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I add a category for NSObject

```
@interface NSObject (Test)
- (nonnull NSString *)nameOfClass;
@end
@implementation NSObject (Test)
-(NSString *)nameOfClass {
    return [self new_nameOfClass];
}
@end
```

when using, I can use it as a class function.

```
Objc
[UITableViewCell nameOfClass];
swift
UITableViewCell.nameOfClass()
```

but If I create a sub class of NSObject, and add a function using category

```
@interface TestObject : NSObject
@end
@interface TestObject (Test)
- (nonnull NSString *)testFunction;
@end
@implementation NSObject (Test)
-(NSString *) testFunction {
    return @"testFunction";
}
@end
```

I can not use it as

```
[TestObject testFunction];
```

if I create a extension for NSObject

```
@objc
public extension NSObject {
    @objc(new_nameOfClass)
    func new_nameOfClass() -> String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }
}
```

I can use it as a class function in Objc file, but. I can not use it in swift.

```
[TestObject new_nameOfClass]; 

TestObject.new_nameOfClass()
error: Instance member 'new_nameOfClass' cannot be used on type 'TestObject'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
```

**Questions**

1. why NSObject's category's instance function can be used as class function?
2. why it not work in NSObject's subclass?
3. why swift's extension for NSObject don't have. same behavior?

please refer these docs.
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html
http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html

Comment: FWIW you can have *both* a class and an instance function in Objective-C with the same name. This might trip you over if you have both defined accidentally.

Comment: I think it's will be helpful: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html

Comment: @Cy-4AH thanks, it really good for me

Answer (score 0):

make that function as class function

objective c

```
 @interface TestObject : NSObject
    @end
    @interface TestObject (Test)
    + (nonnull NSString *)testFunction;
    @end
    @implementation NSObject (Test)
    +(NSString *) testFunction {
        return @"testFunction";
    }
    @end
```